# Docusign OAuth2 Authorization Code flow gets stuck when user has multiple accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi

We build a product that integrates with DocuSign's API. When the customer connects our product to DocuSign, we surface an OAuth2 login flow to authenticate the integration.

This has been working for most customers, but we've found that when a customer has multiple docusign accounts to choose from, the OAuth2 flow gets stuck and never redirects back to our service.

Flow:

- User signs in to DocuSign using their email address
- They click "allow" on the permission prompt
- Docusign prompts them with the screenshot below (I excluded the email addresses to pick from below the explanation for privacy reasons):

[image]

When they select one of the email addresses, the page does not do anything. Are we doing something wrong on our end? Or is this a bug in DocuSign's authentication flow?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the expected behavior.  I've reached out to you via LinkedIn with my contact information and would love to take a look at what's going on from the back end.